# MYSQL: Like Method, Similar Words - But Don't Show the Searched Word

Tags: mysql, sql-like

actually i use this method to show similar words for a search request..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM searches WHERE Query LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY Query";
```

if someone searches for "nelly" it looks up in the database for similar words

"nelly furtado, nelly ft. kelly"...

but i dont want to show up the searched word..

example: you've searched for nelly - try this too: **nelly**, nelly furtado, nelly ft.,

the bold word should not showed up again, because it's the searched word.. is there maybe a method with MATCH AGAINST? thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like `...WHERE Query LIKE "%$search%' AND Query <> '$search'...`?

Case-insensitive: `Query LIKE "%$search%' AND STRCMP(Query, '$search') == 0`

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi, I think this may be due to case sensitivity. I have updated the query to reflect a case-insensitive search.

Comment: Oh sorry. It works. I typed the query incorrectly. The query I tried was this: SELECT * FROM searches WHERE search LIKE '%nelly%' ORDER BY search and
search <> 'nelly'; hehehe :)

Answer (score 0):

`Leniel` - It might be due to capitalization that search term is still showing up, i.e. `*LIKE "nelly"*` will find `"nelly"`, `"Nelly"`, `"NeLlY"`, etc. whereas `* <> "nelly"*` will **only** exclude `"nelly"` (lowercase) from the results.

Perhaps NOT LIKE would yield better results, or `str_to_lower` your input before it leaves PHP and compare it to `LOWER(column_name)` to match all cases.